# Angular 4 - How can I retrieve id in next url by clicking on specific post?

Tags: angular

I want to clik on specific post(product.component) and retrieve its id on next url(details.component). Thank you in advance !

product.component.html

```
 <div class="card">
    <h5>{{titre}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{description}}</p>
    <p><a [routerLink]="['details',id]">Click here!</a></p>
  </div>
```

product.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() titre:string;
  @Input() description:string;
  @Input() id:string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  title = 'home works!';

  products = [{
    titre:"titre1",
    desc:"desc1",
    id:"0"
  },{
    titre:"titre2",
    desc:"desc2",
    id:"1"
  },{
    titre:"titre3",
    desc:"desc3",
    id:"2"
  }];

}
```

details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    id:any;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    DetailsComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'product',
        component: ProductComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'details/:id',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="home">
  <div class="album text-muted">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <product
        class="col-md-4"
        *ngFor="let p of products"
        [description]="p.desc"
        [id]="p.id"
        [titre]="p.titre">
      </product>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes make sure that you're defining the `id` as an argument.

```
{
  path: 'details/:id',
  component: DetailsComponent
}
```

Then update your DetailsComponent to this...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public id: any;
  private idSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      console.log(params.id)
      this.id = params.id;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.idSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSubmit = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work! It show error on this."route"   =>  Property 'route' does not exit on type 'DetailsComponent '

Comment: Have you tried console logging the params.id in the subscription?

Also, did you update your routes, cause that should work.

Comment: How is your Product component getting it's inputs... The input is usually used for attributes of a component, but you seem to be routing to it instead.

Comment: yes, first of all you'll reach to home.component which call product.component then each product has its own details. So when you click on details it redirect to details/:id and retrieve the id in url. That's the principle

Comment: Can you make a plunkr?

Comment: How ?! which files you need to look at !

Comment: Well the logic should work, so I'm curious if there is something else there that's missing. Is this project public on GitHub?

Comment: Hey, would you mind pushing up your changes? It looks like the only commit is the CLI initializing the project/repo.

Comment: Ran your code, made a simple mistake in my above answer, updating it now to what worked (just declared the `route` as `public`).